# WiFi planning tool

Tags: wifi

I am going to build a complex wifi network in a large building, so I am looking for a kind of software, which can:

- Plan APs positions on a map (ex: floor map)
- Draw AP's theoretical coverage (including such factors as walls is a plus)
- Trial,Demo version or even Free

I am not looking for a tool, which will draw coverage of already placed APs, I need to plan AP's positions before mounting them.

Happy New Year!

Comment: I'd like to see something like that as well.  Although Visio and the circle tool will probably be your best bet.

Comment: man this is a massive ask. I *hope* something like this exists, but very much doubt it. There are so many factors that cause QRM I can't imagine trying to map them all, never mind software being able to guess at them without massive amounts of user input.

Comment: @Dayton Brown: Well, I've thought about it already =). But... What if there is one).
@MidnighToker: There are tools like I discribed, but they are paid, without any demo or trial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a closer look at the tools from [ekahau](http://www.ekahau.com/).
Especially ekahau *Site Survey* & ekahau *HeatMapper*.

Best regards...

Comment: I was able to get 30days trial version of Site Survey. It's Nice!

Answer (score 0):

RSOFT Design Group has a product called MetroWand that might be the ticket.

Comment: Well, its for wiring networking.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen anything remotely similar is when a client got an external company in to do a proper analysis for a WiFi deployment in a large warehouse. They had proper equipment, graphs, power levels and so on. I'm afraid I'm not sure whether they used an actual piece of software or just took the floor plan, power levels etc and planned it all using pen and paper.

Other suggestion would be to rig up some test equipment - [WiSpy](http://www.metageek.net/products/wi-spy-24x) might help - and try and work out what channels, placement etc would be best from that

Comment: Well, i won't minus you, but your suggestion is not for my question ;)

Comment: True - but at the same time I don't think you can plan the placement without considering the coverage. I wouldn't want to make any guesses as to theoretical coverage without being incredibly conservative as you have no idea of the environmental factors until you actually get something running.

Answer (score 0):

WiTuners does exactly what you are looking for. It's free if your deployment is not very large.