# wireless network for about 100 clients using home-grade equipment

Tags: wifi, router, access-point, openwrt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Let me say that I have already read a similar question here - [High client density, low cost wifi network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/360073/high-client-density-low-cost-wifi-network)

However, I do not have very low budgetary constraints. However, I am in India and specialized equipment gets to be exponentially much more expensive than in the US. Which is why I need to build it using home-grade wifi equipment.

I just need 100 users of a small office on two floors to be on the same LAN and be able to access the internet through a single fiber optic line. I'm perfectly fine drawing an ethernet cable to connect the various access points, if necessary.

Any idea how to do it ? My max bandwidth is going to be something like 8-12 mbps.

Comment: Does it have to be wireless?  That's going to add a lot of cost, especially with consumer grade gear - even enterprise-grade APs have trouble handling more than a couple dozen concurrent clients, and with consumer-grade gear, you'd be lucky to get ten users per AP.  On the other hand, you can pickup 2 or 3 48 port, unmanaged switches pretty cheap.  (At least in the us, they're only a few hundred bucks a piece.)

Comment: My problem is wiring cost which is turning out to be pretty expensive for us. I was wondering if there is a way to get 4-5 30$ routers to able to route 100 users. It will prove to be big saving for us (and to avoid the problem of our wiring developing a fault - which is pretty common with the quality of wiring)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is marked a duplicate of "capacity planning". I'm asking a question on how to do it with today's home-grade hardware which has gotten to be pretty good. There is not a single answer on serverfault which actually proposes a solution - every one of them asks you to buy commercial equipment. May I point you to AirJaldi if you want to see an example of hacking together a wireless network in the most inhospitable conditions.

Comment: ServerFault is unique in the StackExchange network in the way it's geared towards *professionals*. I realise your budget but no-one in their right mind would "hack together a wireless network" to use, reliably. 8-12MBps is not a lot but any consumer gear starts to fall apart once your approach double-digit connections.

Comment: A) No, there's not going to be any way to do this with 4 or 5 $30 routers.  With consumer-grade gear, you'll need *at least* 1 per 10 concurrent users (and probably closer to one per 5 users) if you expect to provide a reliable connection, and at that point, you're going to run into issues with AP over-saturation.  B) It got marked as a duplicate because it largely is.  C) I would honestly recommend eBay (etc) where you could buy used or end-of-life enterprise-grade WAPs.  You could probably run your wifi network on a few Cisco 1242 APs, and eBay has them for as little as $25 used or $200 new.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd buy a couple [MikroTik Routerboard RB751G-2HnD](http://routerboard.com/RB751G-2HnD) and configure them with [WDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system). MikroTik is a phenomenal value and I can testify to the fact that it's rock solid. Putting two of these in place should be able to shoulder the load you're looking to throw at it.